# How to set active tab in Tab from Material UI by code

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

First time asking on SO, I know that this question was asked lot of times. I already visit all those posts but without sucess unfortunately.

As the title says, I need to change the active tab by code. I am using the material ui scrollable tabs with react.
I thought that the project I am working on maybe it has something bad, so I made [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-dawn-eqiw5?file=/src/App.js:63-117) codesandbox to try without success aswell.

Could you please give me a hint on how to do this on the given example?

Thanks in advance for all the help, this community is awesome!
Best regards

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! what do you mean to change Tabs by code? On which event do you want to change tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a way to manually set a tab, without hitting the actual tab button.

If yes, all you need to do is to change the state that holds the tab's value using `setValue` and provide the number of the tab you want to go (starting from 0).

`e.g. setValue(2)` will take you to the third tab.

You can take a look on [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/modern-morning-x7ku8?file=/src/App.js). I have created a static button that change the state to a specific number, just to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: setValue(IndexOfTab --- here). Whereever you wanted to change the tab in code.